# Toggle divs automatically closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using toggle functionality and it seems that the toggle button is self closing without a reason. It appears and it closes straight after. The code I am using is very simple:

```
    (function($) {
$(document).on("tap", ".Hide-1", function () {
    $(".div-1").hide("slow");

});
$(document).on("tap", ".Reply-open-button-1", function () {
    $("div.Reply-div-1").toggle("slow");

    $("div.Alert-div-1").hide("slow");
    $("div.Close-div-1").hide("slow");
});
$(document).on("tap", ".Alert-open-button-1", function () {
    $("div.Alert-div-1").toggle("slow");

    $("div.Reply-div-1").hide("slow");
    $("div.Close-div-1").hide("slow");
});
$(document).on("tap", ".Close-open-button-1", function () {
    $("div.Close-div-1").toggle("slow");

    $("div.Reply-div-1").hide("slow");
    $("div.Alert-div-1").hide("slow");
});

})(jQuery);
```

I am also using ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'](http://'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')

Can you see any potential reason why would it self close when I tap on any of them?

Thanks in advance N!

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: Yes, please show us the DOM, there might be an issue with event propagation.